# how to get ride of grammar file for MS voice recognition?

Tags: grammar, voice-recognition

I'm using MS SAPI for voice recognition, and just thinking how to get ride of the grammar file? It's easier to just give an input string with several commands, and it will be nice to modify that input command list instead of revise the grammar file. Which API should I pass my input string? I can write code to generate the grammar file, the question is -- why it's necessary to include a separate file? I understand in grammar file it gives the language model, it should be done somewhere else. Sometimes it takes time to explain how to use it to someone who never used it before. Any idea to get ride of the grammar file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've generated grammar file from command list, and user just need to give command they wants.